# $1 + \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(x - i)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How to show that $1 + \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(x - i)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ for all $n \ne 4$? If I suppose by contradiction that it is reducible, as $p(x)q(x)$, then we can assume without loss of generality that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are both monic. We also have that $p(i)q(i) = 1$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Can I draw a contradiction from this? Or should I try something else

Comment: Yes, the contradiction will follow from the fact that $p(i)q(i)=1$ means that either $(p(i),q(i))=(1,1)$ or $(p(i),q(i))=(-1,-1)$. Then using a degree argument you should be able to show this is impossible.

Comment: Actually it is irreducible for $n=2$ and $n=3$, too

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Why does this argument fail in the case $n=4$ ?

Comment: @Raffaele And also for $n=1$ :)

Comment: @Peter You are right! $$(x-4) (x-3) (x-2) (x-1)+1=\left(x^2-5 x+5\right)^2$$

Comment: I checked the polynomials upto $n=500$ with PARI/GP and found no reducible polynomial except for $n=4$

Answer (score 2):

Hints: note that for $1\leq i\leq n$, $p(i)=q(i)$ (why?). Hence $p(x)-q(x)$ has $n$ roots, but has degree smaller than $n$, so $p(x)=q(x)$. Therefore your polynomial is a square. This is impossible for odd $n$, clearly. For even $n\geq 6$, evaluate at $x=1.5$ to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r(x)=1+\prod_{k=1}^n(x-k)$. Assume that $r=pq$.

At least one of the polynomials $p$ or $q$ has degree $\le n/2$. Assume that it is $p$. Note that $p(i)^2=1$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Then $p^2$ and $r$ has the same values at $n$ points, and they are monic, so
$$p(x)^2=r(x)$$

But $r(n+1)=n!+1$, that is a perfect square for $n=4,5,7$. Paul Erdős conjectured that there are no more integer numbers $n$ such that $n!+1$ is a square. See [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem).

Nonetheless, for even $n\ge 6$,
$$r(1.5)=1-\frac{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-3)}{2^n}<1-\frac{945}{64}<0$$